# Is it possible to disable cache for stormpath in python?

Tags: python, caching, stormpath

I'm using the `RedisStore` as a [cache store](http://docs.stormpath.com/python/product-guide/#caching) for stormpath. The problem with the default `MemoryStore` is that it doesn't work properly for multiple webservers behind the load-balancer.

Now what I'd like to do is to disable caching completely if the redis server is down.

How do I disable the caching for the stormpath so every time I read from or write to the stormpath an actual request is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new NullCache in the latest release =) https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-python/blob/master/stormpath/cache/null_cache_store.py

Comment: Perfect! =) Thank you.